# Adding Highcharts data function using the plugin WPDataTables

Tags: javascript, wordpress, highcharts

I have a table that is produced using the plugin WPDataTables, however I then need to make a graph from it. When the graph (using the same plugin) is made, the series and X-axis are the wrong way round. The plugin calls in highcharts do make the graph and I saw that you can do Highcharts callbacks to the API. E.g:

```
obj.options.chart.panning = true;
```

However, that seems to not cover the full API, specifically to the data module to do callbacks involving the table, e.g.:

```
obj.options.data.switchRowsAndColumns = true;
```

My reason for this is that the way I need to produce a table so I can use the filter function (which the graph will be linked to), would produce a graph where the series and x-axis are the wrong way round.

Please let me know if this feature is possible, and if not, whether there will be a possible workaround?

Comment: I think that you should be able to fix it by using the `complete` callback. Take a look for the API and the included demo: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete If this wouldn't help please reproduce your case on some online editor with a sample data.

Comment: I've had a look at the demo example however they're getting their data from CSV, if mine is from a table that is loaded from a plugin, what do i put as the data source?

Comment: Also the graph is also produced by the plugin even though it is using highcharts, the callbacks are meant to provide additional options but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/muk57toe/ data is taken from the table and could be edit in the `complete` callback